# having trouble making my start button convert to stop

Tags: javascript, animation, event-handling

**This is what i have so far**

```
 <script>
 var robot = null

  }
```

//**initiates movement

```
 var moveRight = function(){
 robot.style.left = parseInt(robot.style.left) + 10 +'px';
 }

 window.onload =init;
 </script>
 </head>
 </html>

<body>
```

//**initiates buttons convert for movement**

```
<form>
<img id = "ted" src = "Ted.png"/>
<p>Click button to move image to right</p>
<input type = "button" value = "start" onlick = "moveRight"();"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, syntax error in this line:

```
<input type = "button" value = "start" onlick = "moveRight"();"/>
```

That's invalid JavaScript and the attribute is called "onclick". Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="moveRight();" />
```